# how to read numbers only as a matrix ignoring brackets in the original file?

Tags: matlab

how to read numbers only as a matrix from .txt in matlab of this format
The file is like this:

[9.8 3.3 5.8 2.5 ]

[9.4 4.2 5.2 2.5 ]

[9.2 2.1 5.8 1.6 ]

[8.2 8.6 5.8 2.8 ]

[2.1 3.3 5.8 2.5 ]

I want to ignore brackets

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the format of your file when using [readtable](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/readtable.html) with the *Format* field.

From the documentation:

> Column format of the file, specified as the comma-separated pair consisting of 'Format' and a character vector or a string of one or more conversion specifiers.

In the code below, we indicate that the text documents consists of a character  ( the first square bracket [ ), followed by four floating point numbers, ending with a second character ( the second square bracket ]). Specifier '**%c**' is used for characters, specifier '**%f**' for floating point numbers.

The table constructed will have six columns, Var1 and Var6 contain the square bracket character, the other four contain the actual numerical data.

The output is therefore obtained by concatenating the columns of interest: Var2,Var3,Var4,Var5.

```
T = readtable('sample.txt','Format','%c%f%f%f%f%c','ReadVariableNames',false);
num = [T.Var2 T.Var3 T.Var4 T.Var5];
```

The output of **num** is the matrix that you require:

```
num =

9.8000    3.3000    5.8000    2.5000
9.4000    4.2000    5.2000    2.5000
9.2000    2.1000    5.8000    1.6000
8.2000    8.6000    5.8000    2.8000
2.1000    3.3000    5.8000    2.5000
```